# Bug When Trying to Sort with Lodash Angular 6

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, sorting, lodash

I have an array which needs to remove duplicate records and then leave the record with the most clicks

[image]

I need this group to show two records, one with 7 clicks and the other 3 clicks.

I have narrowed a very long-winded set of problems down to these few lines of code (the first map method) which if in place, sends an empty object back to the browser on ngOnInit().

This is the method:

```
getCommissions(){
    this.commissions$ = this.analyticsService.getAllCommissionData().pipe(
      map((commissionData: {data: Commission[]}) => {<--problem code
        const commissions = commissionData.data;<--problem code
        return _.uniqBy(commissions.sort((a, b) => b.clicks - a.clicks), commission => commission.page_url);<--problem code
      }), 
      map((commissionData: {data: Commission[]}) => {
        const commissions = commissionData.data;
        return _.groupBy(commissions, commission => commission.page_type)
      }),
      catchError(err => {
        this.errorObject = err;
        console.log(this.errorObject);
        return throwError(err);
      })
    )
  }
```

worth sharing the class too:

```
export class Commission {
    id: number;
    url: string;
    page_url: string;
    page_type: string;
    clicks: number;
}
```

and the html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="commissions$ | async as commissions; else loading">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let page_type of ['home', 'article','statistics', 'products']">
    <h4>{{ page_type | titlecase }}</h4>
    <p *ngIf="!commissions[page_type]">No {{ page_type }} Commissions Logged Yet</p>
    <ul *ngFor="let card of commissions[page_type]">
      <app-click-card [card]="card"></app-click-card>
    </ul>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-container *ngIf="errorObject"> 
  {{ errorObject }}
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading>
    <h4>Loading ...</h4>
</ng-template>
```

I have a [stackblitz of an example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3kchji?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts). But I can't seem to work out why the first map won't run properly with lodash - the data is set properly and the sort doesn't bring up any errors, but when sorted (I guess) the result is an empty object.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please share what the expected array looks like after transformation using the sample data in the stackblitz? The example seems to removing duplicates and grouping by the correct property as well as sorting by number of clicks in descending order.

Comment: sure. I'll set this up now.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - can you check to see that this is updated?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qzeyvg

Comment: And yes, the idea is to group the array into page types, then show the highest number of clicks for a particular page_url. i.e. remove duplicates of the record.

Comment: Are you saying **only** the one with highest clicks in each group?

Comment: the highest record with the same page_url. So for example: 

CLICK ORIGIN:
PRODUCT NAME: 3RD JERSEY <--page_url
CLICK THROUGH URL:
HTTPS://SIDELINEAPP.IO
AD CLICKS: 7

CLICK ORIGIN:
PRODUCT NAME: 3RD JERSEY <-- page_url
CLICK THROUGH URL:
HTTPS://SIDELINEAPP.IO
AD CLICKS: 6

- the second record must be removed and leave the top with 7. If that makes sense.

Comment: The stackblitz as it stands is how the data should appear. But breaks on the second map in the real code base.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I think the first suggestion has worked. I had a variable not written correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your first map changes the shape of the data and the second map is no longer receiving an object of type { data: Commission[] }, it receives the output from the first map which will not have a data property, it will already be an array of Commission so

```
const commissions = commissionData.data;
```

is undefined.

Change your second map to

```
map((commissions: Commission[]) => {
  return _.groupBy(commissions, commission => commission.page_type);
}),
```

Comment: Definitely a valid point. In the stackblitz they aren’t extracting property data though so it’s not as much of issue.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have added this in, but the array only shows the last group and only one record. :/

Comment: I had commissionData sorting instead of commissions - I fixed and it is now displaying correctly. Thank you Adrian. This has taken me most of the day to get it right. Thanks so much for your help! You won't be able to see the relief on my face right now!!!! :D But it's there.